# A measure is a linear form on the continuous functions of compact support

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, distribution-theory

I'm reading the book "Linear Partial Differential Operators I" by Hormander. I don't understand the identification of a measure as a linear form. The definition of a linear form that appears in the book is the following:

Definition. A distribution $u$ on $X$ is a linear form on $\mathcal{C}_{0}^{\infty}(X)$ such that for every compact set $K\subset X$, there exist constants $C$ and $k$ such that

$$(2.1.2)\qquad\qquad|u(\phi)|\leq C\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k}\sup|\partial^{\alpha}\phi|,\quad \phi\in\mathcal{C}_{0}^{\infty}(K)$$

Subsequently, it is mentioned that:

A measure can be defined as a linear form on $\mathcal{C}_{0}^{0}(X)$ with the continuity property $(2.1.2)$ for $k=0.$

Question. Does the identification of a measure $\mu$ arise from $\mu(\phi)=\int \phi(x)d\mu(x)$? I don't understand that part. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, so does it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem

Comment: But $|u(\phi)|\leq \sup |\phi| \int d\mu(x)$ with $\int_{X} d\mu(x)<\infty$?

Comment: Not $\int_{X} d\mu(x)<\infty$ but $|\mu|(K),$ where $\phi$ has support in $K.$

Comment: As hinted by Anne Beauval it needs to be a Radon measure, it is not true for arbitrary measures (that can assign $+\infty$ to some intervals)